# How do I pull individual XML values from an existing BLOB

Tags: xml, oracle, blob, xmltype

I have a blob which I don't own and cannot change. It is a BLOB containing an XML message which I want to ***parse***.

[xml from schema browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THST5.png)

---

My parse attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT
   XMLTYPE( t.intfc_rqst_xml ).EXTRACT('//*/text()').getStringVal() 
FROM
   INTERFACE_MESSAGE_INFO t;
```

---

Gives this Error

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character set is a second parameter.

You can try the following:

```
...
xmltype(t.intfc_rqst_xml , nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
...
```

**Different Character Sets**

| IANA | Oracle |
| --- | --- |
| UTF-8 | AL32UTF8 |
| ISO-8859-1 | WE8ISO8859P1 |
| ISO-8859-15 | WE8ISO8859P15 |
| WINDOWS-1252 | WE8MSWIN1252 |

Comment: The query output is large than 4000 characters. Try to remove `.EXTRACT('//*/text()').getStringVal() ` and see the output. Your current query takes all textual nodes and lumps them together.